# Savechange swapping one index by another

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My entity is like that:

```
public class Foo
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Bar has a unique index.

In my code I get two Foo objects:

```
object 1: { Id: 1, Bar: 1}
object 2: { Id: 2, Bar: 2}
```

What I need to do is to swap one by other:

```
object 1: { Id: 1, Bar: 2}
object 2: { Id: 2, Bar: 1}
```

and update this in a transaction.
But when I do this, I get an error similar to that:

```
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Episode' with unique index 'IX_Id_Season_Number'. The duplicate key value is (2f649a95-0a03-e511-9751-0090f5a7af27, 3, 1).
The statement has been terminated.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have an additional update for one of the objects where `Bar` is set to some dummy value that meets your constraint, since constraints are evaluated per update and not per transaction. Here's some pseudocode:

```
object 1: { Id: 1, Bar: 2}  
object 2: { Id: 2, Bar: -1} // or some other dummy value
save
object 2: { Id: 2, Bar: 1}
save
```

Since you're putting everything within a transaction, you won't have to worry about the database ending up in the intermediate state if something goes wrong.

**See**

- [Swap unique indexed column values in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644/swap-unique-indexed-column-values-in-database)
- [How to swap values of two rows in MySQL without violating unique constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207574/how-to-swap-values-of-two-rows-in-mysql-without-violating-unique-constraint)
- [Swapping values with unique constraint in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226565/swapping-columns-with-unique-constraint-in-entity-framework)

Comment: "constraints are evaluated per update and not per transaction" - this is an incredibly important statement.